How do I prevent large table writes from hanging the database?
I have a Percona 8 MySQL Server, running via Docker, acting as the backing data store for a heavily used service.
On the hour, a script will run that reads a value from a virtual column of approximately 1.7 million rows (Table size estimate of 2.3 GiB) and inserts this particular value and the associated key data into another table that the system otherwise only reads from. The virtual column is a JSON lookup json_extract(jsonData, '$.root.interestingValue') and has the GENERATED flag.
The idea behind this is to put less pressure on the table that is considered live and updated regularly, when users are only interested in a few specific values and retrieving the absolute latest value is not required.
The query is as follows (with tables/columns renamed)
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_cache_temp
SELECT
  t2.id as uid,
  t3.displayText as dt,
  t2.virtualColumn as interestingValue
FROM liveTable t2
JOIN otherLiveTable t3 on t2.id = t3.id;

TRUNCATE TABLE t1_cache;

INSERT INTO t1_cache
SELECT uid, dt, interestingValue FROM t1_cache_temp;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE t1_cache_temp;

The total time taken by this script is 47 seconds.
Whilst reading from the InnoDB table and writing to the temporary table is fine, writing it to the other InnoDB table causes all other operations on the database to hang after the first few seconds.
I narrowed it down to the INSERT INTO t1_cache... statement by executing each statement individually.
I have also tried writing to new and completely unused tables (also using InnoDB), which gives the same result. At the time of performing the last test, only 2% of the permitted Max Connections are in use. Also, only 48% of the InnoDB Buffer Pool was in use.
If I switch the table to MyISAM, everything works normally, with no interruption or hanging. Additionally, if I remove the temporary table, it causes the same issue regardless of InnoDB or MyISAM engine.
Whilst using MyISAM is probably the better option anyway, what could be causing this? Is there anything I can do about it at a configuration level?

What's your configuration for innodb_log_file_size? It could be causing checkpoints if your 2.3GiB transaction is causing the log file to fill multiple times.

Currently it's set to 50.331.648, with a buffer size of 16.777.216. I was advised that this would be sufficient, as the output from the transform would be a maximum of 92 bytes per row. This would lead to ~4 checkpoints if my understanding is right?

You said your writes are 2.3GiB, but the InnoDB redo log size is 48MiB.  I estimate one such write would fill the redo log more than 49 times.
The InnoDB redo log has a fixed size. Writes don't append or make it larger, they make it wrap around and overwrite the log file. Each time it does this, InnoDB must pause SQL, and flush dirty pages from the buffer pool to disk until a good portion of the redo log is not needed. This won't necessarily be the whole redo log, it might be just enough for MySQL to think it can allow more writes. So one 2.3GiB write may result in hundreds of checkpoints.
I recommend reading this blog post to get a good explanation of how the log file size affects throughput: https://www.percona.com/blog/what-is-a-big-innodb_log_file_size/
The default InnoDB redo log size is 48MiB. This is sufficient only for an application with very low write traffic. For instance, a WordPress blog, which is largely read-only, and when writes occur, they are small.
If there's enough storage space, I would increase the redo log to 4GiB if you want to allow easier throughput of the occasional 2.3GiB writes.
It's an advantage to size the log file with a comfortable margin, because a checkpoint is triggered when the log is 3/4 full. See https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/04/04/innodb-flushing-theory-and-solutions/ for details on this.

P.S. I don't use MyISAM if I can avoid it. See my answer here for a reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb/17706717#17706717

Hi Bill, apologies as it may have not been clear in my original question then, the table I'm reading from is 2.3GiB, however, the output after writing is 140.5MiB (data length ~35.5MiB)
I can perform the recommendation of increasing the log file size anyway. Also thank you for the Percona blog links, I have struggled to know exactly what search terms to use when Googling this issue :)

Okay, I hope the explanation was helpful. It seems even a 35.5MiB write might trigger the checkpoint on a redo log of the default size. The default size is really undersized for production traffic on most modern applications.

Yes. I appreciate your explanation of what's probably going on. I'm going to try adjusting the log sizes during our next maintenance window and I'll report back whether or not it works.

That script is doing twice as much work as necessary.  Change to
CREATE  TABLE t1_cache_temp   -- not TEMPORARY
SELECT
  t2.id as uid,
  t3.displayText as dt,
  t2.virtualColumn as interestingValue
FROM liveTable t2
JOIN otherLiveTable t3 on t2.id = t3.id;

RENAME TABLE t1_cache TO t1_old,
             t1_cache_temp TO t1_cache,
DROP TABLE t1_old;

